# Identifing a function with another function

Tags: calculus, analysis

For a given real function $g(x)$, how can we find all functions $f(x)$ with the condition $$f(x)f(-x)=g(x)$$ For example, let $g(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n\in\mathbb{N}$, or be a trigonometric function, can we find $f(x)$ with above condition?

Comment: Well, you need to have $g(x)=f(x)f(-x)=f(-x)f(-(-x))=g(-x)$, to be able to find such $f$.

Comment: The function $g$ must be evn.

Comment: @S.Nosrati $f= |x|$

Comment: @clark Sorry, I made a mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(x)f(-x)=f(-x)f(-(-x))$, so for it to be possible, you must have $g(x)=g(-x)$ for all $x$. Also, $g(0)=f(0)^2$, so $g(0)$ can't be negative.

If these conditions are met, you can set *any nonzero values* for $f(x)$ at all positive $x$ and then define $f(-x)=\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ and $f(0)=\pm\sqrt{g(0)}$. Furthermore, for any $x$ such that $g(x)=0$, you can also have $f(x)=0$ and $f(-x)$ be arbitrary.

In short, this is impossible for most $g(x)$, but for the ones where it is possible, there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: $f(0)=\pm\sqrt{g(0)}$

Comment: Thanks. but i forgot to mention that $f$ must be continuous, what's the answer in this case?

Comment: @S.Nosrati Assuming $g$ is continuous, you just have to choose any continuous $f(x)$ for nonnegative $x$ with no zeroes and with $f(0)=\pm\sqrt{g(0)}$, and define $f(-x)$ the same way as in this answer. This will be continuous because the ratio of two continuous functions is also continuous (if the denominator is never zero).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to have $g(x)=f(x)f(-x)=f(-x)f(-(-x))=g(-x)$, i.e. $g$ must be even, to be able to find such $f$. Moreover, you need $g(0)=f(0)^2\ge0$.

Now, suppose $g$ satisfies these conditions. Set $f(0)=\pm g(0)^{1/2}$ and let $A=\mathbb R ^+\cap \{x\in\mathbb R\:g(x)=0\}$. Choose a random value for $f(x)$ for all $x\in A$, and choose a random non-zero value for all other $x\in \mathbb R^+$. THis uniquely determines $f$.